# TabItem does not refresh when list of tabItem has changed in SWT

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

Below is my code, When button press I am changing the item1 list by using **item1.setcontrol** depends on my condition.
Composite is not refreshing, But when I click on Item2 tab and come back to Item1 tab... List is updated depends on condition.
Please let me know How to refresh the layout with out moving to other Tab item.

```
    final Composite RightComposite = new Composite(paComposite, SWT.NONE);
    RightComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
    RightComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, GridData.FILL, true, true));


    Composite findComposite = new Composite(RightComposite, SWT.NONE);
    findComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, true));
    findComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, GridData.FILL, true, false));

    txt = new Text(findComposite, SWT.BORDER | SWT.WRAP | SWT.SINGLE);
    txt.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, GridData.FILL, true, false));
    txt.addListener(SWT.Verify, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(final Event e)
        {
            newString = ((Text) e.widget).getText();
        }
    });
    btn = new Button(findTCComposite, SWT.NONE);
    btn.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.BEGINNING, GridData.BEGINNING, false, false));
    btn.setText("Find button");
    final TabFolder tabFolder = new TabFolder(RightComposite, SWT.NONE);
    tabFolder.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, GridData.FILL, true, true));

    final TabItem item1 = new TabItem(tabFolder, SWT.NONE);
    item1.setText("Tab 1 ");
    btn.addListener (SWT.Selection,  new Listener()
    {           
        public void handleEvent(Event e) {
                if(!newString.isEmpty()){
                    item1.setControl(list1);
                }
                else
                {
                    item1.setControl(list);
                }
        }
    });

    TabItem item2 = new TabItem(tabFolder, SWT.NONE);
    Item2.setText("Tab 2");
    RightComposite.layout();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in the SWT's TabItem class, in the setControl() function. At the end of this function it makes an: oldControl.setVisible (false);

So in your situation the oldControl will be the same control you set (it you set it twice) and it will be hidden. To solve the problem you can modify the code as:

```
btn.addListener (SWT.Selection,  new Listener() {           
    public void handleEvent(Event e) {
            if (!newString.isEmpty()) {
                item1.setControl(list1);
                list1.setVisible(true);
            } else {
                item1.setControl(list);
                list.setVisible(true);
            }
    }
});
```

Or another approach:

```
btn.addListener (SWT.Selection,  new Listener() {           
    public void handleEvent(Event e) {
            if (newString != null && !newString.isEmpty()) {
                if (item1.getControl() != list1) {
                    item1.setControl(list1);
                }
            } else {
                if (item1.getControl() != list) {
                    item1.setControl(list);
                }
            }
    }
});
```

I hope this fits your needs.